# Sci-fi/fantasy book that I read in the mid to late 90s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The book has a series of short stories all connected to a community outside the city full of industry. The story starts with a young boy with a scar on his face that he is always covering with his hand because he is embarrassed by it. He eventually finds his way to this community that is maybe in a forest and several of the stories follow different characters in this community. There are characters like rangers, breakers, dragons, etc. Does anyone remember anything like this??

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?  The names of any of the characters?  And what is a "breaker?"

Comment: I don't remember any character names. A breaker is an evil type character tasked with punishing and returning escaped individuals to the city. Their antithesis are the rangers, who defend the community. I think the cover art had a dragon on it, but it's been so long I could be mistaken.

Comment: It's a book geared for children with Christian undertones if that helps.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by th voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

I think this is probably [Tales of the Kingdom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1006442.Tales_of_the_Kingdom) by David and Karen Mains.

[image: Tales of the Kingdom]

The boy is known only as *Scarboy*. The scar on his face was from an accident when he was branded (all children have brands put on their hands at age five). The city is ruled by *The Enchanter*, and his henchmen are *Burners* - not *Breakers*. The book is about the search for the one true King.

The book is part one of [the Tales of the Kingdom trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_the_Kingdom_Trilogy).

The [Amazon listing for the book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tales-Kingdom-David-Mains/dp/1584740507) has a "look inside" that contains the first story so you can skim this to see if it is the book you remember.